# 12.04 64bit crashing on old HPDV5000

Tags: 12.04, laptop

As stated in title I have an old HP dv5000 laptop (amd 64bit). I have it set up as a dual boot winXP media center which runs fine, and have used MacPup off a cd - running in ram - no problem. I have successfully set up a desktop with the same configuration (but a much newer - though still older system). 
Problem: I have tried to install 3 times and the installation is just unstable. As soon as I run an app - or try to install software the system crashes - black screen with text. I started running memtest86+ from the hard drive, and got errors in the second, third and fifth tests but had to use the system so stopped and rebooted into windows.

Can this be bad ram? - but then why does windows work fine, and running MacPup in ram works fine?
Is the Ubuntu too much for this old system?

I will go back and run memory tests with memtest86+ and the old windows memory test software - but in mean time - I had the chance - between freelance jobs to ask this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

One more note: I am only techie enough to keep my computer systems working and upgrading as needed to do my freelancing. Mostly use windows, but have in past used Mac. I like Linux and really like Ubuntu - so was hoping to get this working on the old laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be bad RAM. However, software may *appear* to work fine, only until the bad section of the memory is accessed. When it does get accessed, the application accessing it, will probably crash. It may be that in your normal usage of Windows, you are rarely hitting the point in the memory where it is bad, or you are simply expecting things on Windows to crash, and expecting them not to on Ubuntu. It is quite difficult to make a direct comparison between the two systems, as you will personally have different expectations of their behavior, the software is different, and your usage of the software is different.

Comment: Thanks for the observation - will run the two ram tests asap. Yes I do expect windows to be more crash prone - but as you say - they are different.

Comment: Quick possibly note: I did get a chance to run Ubuntu off the CD and it works fine - as does MacPup.

Comment: Just a follow up for fellow rookie Unbuntu users. It turned out that I had a faulty ram stick and it kept messing up the installation of Ubuntu. Checked the stick in three tests isolated and in different slots. Popped in another stick and - all went well. First time I have had bad ram.